# Getting data about football players from DBpedia using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I have never used DBpedia/SPARQL before.

How can I make a query to select, let's say all (or top 100) football players, also selecting their Date of birth, Playing position and Height. I would prefer the result to be in JSON if that's possible :D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?player a <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/SoccerPlayer> .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate> ?birthDate .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person/height> ?height .
  ?player <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/position> ?position .
}
```

Select all ?player who is a soccerPlayer, who has a ?birthDate, who has a ?height, who has a ?position, and return all the results.
I think this is the query you need. As for the result format, you can choose it from the endpoint, I don't know if that's what you wanted.